# Save all passed values using for each statement

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, foreach

I have an Object and I am trying to populate it with a passed list of records, the issue I am having is I want to do a For each loop for each record and then return the all records and the end of the function.

**What it is currently doing:**

- `StoreRec` is currently passing 3 records
- It is writing only first record to the DB because there is no loop

**What I want to accomplish:**

- I want to be able to write multiple lines on the DB

**Input:** `StoreRec`

Store1,
Bruise Store,
Germany,
Store2,
Jakes Store,
Bromol,
Store3,
Fred's Store,
Cornices

**Current Output:** `StoreRecord`

Store1,
Bruise Store,
Germany

**Expected output:** `StoreRecord`

Store1,
Bruise Store,
Germany ,
Store2,
Jakes Store,
Bromol,
Store3,
Fred's Store,
Cornices

**Current populate Function:**

```vb
Public Function PopulateStoreRecords(StoreRec As Dictionary(Of String, String)) As Object

    Dim StoreRecord As New StoreDetailRecord

    If StoreRec.ContainsKey("Store Number") Then
        StoreRecord.StoreNumber = StoreRec.Item("Store Number")
    End If
    
    If StoreRec.ContainsKey("Store Name") Then
        StoreRecord.StoreName = StoreRec.Item("Store Name")
    End If
    
    If StoreRec.ContainsKey("Store Location") Then
        StoreRecord.StoreLocation = StoreRec.Item("Store Location")
    End If  

    Return StoreRecord
   
End Function
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: @user18387401 I have updated the question with Input, Current output I am getting and Expected Output

Comment: Could you update your question with example usage of this function?  As is there is no info about any sort of looping nor how you get any sort of collection